# How to append and remove comma seperated values(string) using Jquery

Tags: jquery

Basically i am trying to create similar thing like Jquery Input Token. I will add values via autocomplete(Custom) in to a comma separated string and also would like to give a remove option.

I am facing issues with this, any sort of help will be really appreciated..

Comment: And the question's text is... ?

Comment: You should really try to describe your problem better and also show what you've already tried.

Comment: I have tried to append the clicked element in to a string and i have also added comma with that value but because of that i have to use substring to remove the first comma for the first value and its working.. Now i am looking for the logic to remove a particular value.The comma separated string is hidden and i am giving a cross option above it

Answer (score 7):

I wouldn't use a comma-separated string for this. I'd use an array, and then *convert* that to a comma-separated string when necessary (via `join`).

But:

*Adding* is, of course, easy (assume `data` and `newEntry` are both strings):

```
data += "," + newEntry;
```

or if you want to avoid a leading comma:

```
data = data ? (data + "," + newEntry) : newEntry;
```

*Removing* is slightly more challenging and part of why I wouldn't use a string for this. But you can do something like this:

```
var tmp = data.split(',');
var index = tmp.indexOf(entryToRemove);
if (index !== -1) {
    tmp.splice(index, 1);
    data = tmp.join(',');
}
```

...which uses an array intermediate. Or you could find the entry using `String#indexOf` and remove it by using `String#substring` to grab the bits before and after it, and put them together.

Comment: +1, I've no idea what he asked, but this is a great answer... :)